# Default HDD partitions on Dell Inspiron 3551 laptop

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I got a brand new dell inspiron 15 3551 with ubuntu 14.04 preinstalled.
3,7GB RAM, Intel Celeron CPU N2840 2´16 GHz x2, Graf. Intel Bay Trail, HDD 500GB.
It comes with the following disc partitions;

```
/dev/sda1 (ESP), EFI, 524MB, mounted on /boot/efi.
/dev/sda2 (DIAGS), FAT 32, 42MB, not mounted.
/dev/sda3 (OS), FAT 32, 3´2GB, not mounted.
/dev/sda4 (File System), ext4, 488GB, mounted on /.
/dev/sda5, swap, 8,3GB.
Free space 1´1MB.
```

I´m considering reinstalling ubuntu 14.04 from a USB stick, mainly to repartition the HDD and set the root (/) in one partition and an other one with /home. 
I wonder...
What is the purpose of each ESP, DIAGS and OS partitions? I suppose ESP if for booting. Can I eliminate any of them?
8,3GB of exchange menory is not too much?  How much could I reasignate to Exch. Mem.?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all partitions if you like. But you will lose the recpvery feature that allows to restore everything to factory defaults.

/dev/sda1 is EFI boot. It is needed for UEFI.

/dev/sda3 must be Ubuntu OEM distribution image.

I do not know what /dev/sda2 is for, but it may be also needed for factory restore.

Regarding swap partition that you call "exchange memory" I can say that 4 GB will be enough. Hibernation must work and RAM size is a common size.